# Adding JLabels to a Panel inside a Panel inside another Panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have one "main" panel. I'd like to have a "side" panel inside the main one. The side is composed of two other panels, let's call one graphicPanel and one supportPanel. I'm trying to add labels to the SupportPanel from the main one, but no changes happen.

Here is my side panel:

```
public class LateralSupportPane extends JPanel{

private final static int WIDTH = 240;
private final static int HEIGHT = 740;
private GraphicPanel gp;
private SupportPanel sp;


public LateralSupportPane(){
    this.gp = new GraphicPanel();
    this.sp = new SupportPanel();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    //this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    this.add(gp);
    this.add(sp);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

    public void addLabel(String label){
    sp.addLabel(label);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    gp.paintComponent(g);
}

public void addLabel(String label){
    sp.addLabel(label);
}
```

Here my supportPanel:

```
public class SupportPanel extends JPanel{
private JLabel label;
private final static int WIDTH = 240;
private final static int HEIGHT = 370;

public SupportPanel(){

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("<html>BlaBla</html>");
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
    this.add(label);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public JLabel getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void addLabel(String text){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
    if(this.getComponentCount() < 10){
        this.add(label);
    } else {
        this.remove(0);
        this.add(label);
    }
}
```

From the main panel I call the addLabel of the side panel.

EDIT: Here is the frame with all panels. The board itself is a panel added into a frame. The board also has another panel, that are the black rectangle and the area where the string is, together. Then the side panel is composed by 2 other panels, the GraphicPanel (the black rectangle) and the supportPanel, that is the area where I'd like to have my labels.

[Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H98ag.png)

Validating all panels made no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i undurstend it correctly, but it seams, that you have to validate your panels after inserting new label;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setSize(900, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new CardLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    LateralSupportPane p = new LateralSupportPane();
    frame.add(p);
    frame.validate();
    p.addLabel("test 2");
    p.validate();
}
```

as you see, after adding a label, validation is performed and object is painted on form.
your method `addLabel(String label)` should have this method called at end of it.

Comment: Tried to add validate both in addLabel(String label) and in addLabel(), so inside every panel, but nothing works. I'm adding further explanations in the post.

Comment: That's bit confusing, I've added validation in `LateralSupportPane` method, and it works fine. Can you provide more code so i can compile it your way?

Comment: I know, the structure is confusing but I cannot imagine another way to implement a sort of list of JLabels that are added and removed dynamically in my overall structure. I cannot give you more code because I would have to paste the entire board code and, as you can imagine, is quite massive. Try to put inside the main frame a panel. Inside this panel another panel and in this last one, setting a gridlayout with 2 rows and a column, other 2 panels. In one add the label and call my addLabel(String text) method. Thank you

Comment: why dont you use `JList`? It seams that you need to do sort of chat with movement info. `JList` is much better for that,than `JLabel`

Comment: I did not even know about the existence of JList! Thank you!